# If $\Phi: \mathbf{Vec} \rightarrow \mathbf{Vec}$ with $\Phi(V) = V^{\ast\ast}$ and $f: V \rightarrow W$, what is $\Phi(f)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\Phi$ be an endofunctor of the category of vector spaces over a field which sends a vector space to its double dual. Let $V$ and $W$ be 2 vector spaces and let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a morphism from $V$ to $W$. Then $\Phi(f): V^{\ast\ast} \rightarrow W^{\ast\ast}$, but do I know how $\Phi(f)$ acts on elements of $V^{\ast\ast}$?

Comment: Do you mean the dual or the double dual?

Comment: As @user180040 said, you are stating first that $\Phi$ is the dual functor, but then you're writing as if you're considering the double dual. Dual is contravariant. Double dual (as a composition of the dual with itself) is covariant.

Comment: @user180040, Apologies, I meant double dual instead of dual. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Okay, and you probably mean the *usual* functor, right?

Comment: @user180040: $\Phi$ is any endofunctor which sends a vector space to its double dual. However, I suspect in this case it's too general to say anything. What happens when $\Phi$ is the usual functor?

Comment: It sends $f \colon V \to W$ to the transpose of its transpose.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $V^*=\hom(V,K)$ where $K$ is the base field.

Well, $\Phi(f)$ assigns for an element $\vartheta\in V^{**}=\hom(V^*,K)$ the element of $W^{**}=\hom(W^*,K)$ which sends
$$\underset{W\to K}g\mapsto \vartheta\big(\underset{V\to K}{g\circ f}\big)\,.$$